# Python: efficient way to calculate moving average for fixed time window (NOT fixed observation widnow)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, time, moving-average

**Problem description**

Say I have:

1. vector of `time`, dtype is numpy `datetime64`,
2. vector of `parameters`, dtype is numpy `float`
3. time `horizon`, dtype is numpy `timedelta64`

And `time.shape == parameters.shape`. Values of `time` are unique and distances between elements are not even.

Goal I have: for each moment `t` of time calculate some statistic (for instance mean, min, max, sum, etc.) for the parameters vector for time period from `time[t-horizon]` to `time[t]`

The rookie way would be to use a loop (**I don't want to use a loop for performance reasons**) or some pandas aggregation/resampling (this is however not ideal as I don't want to aggregate - this creates a new time vector, while I want to preserve my `time`.

**My current approach**

I create the following matrix. Matrix visualization is set on real data and shows why I need different range to calculate statistic for every observation separately - sometimes 15min of history has 5,000 observations while sometimes roughly few hundred. This is also something that I measure - how many events occurred within a fixed time horizon.

`past = (time < time[:, None]) & (time>(time- horizon)[:, None]`

`plt.imshow(past)`
[past](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGhmF.png)

**The first problem - creation of the matrix like above for long    observation vectors is time-consuming. Is there a better way to    create such a matrix?** Presented matrix represent real data for one day but this also can be longer (up to 50,000 unique observations but what I'm aiming for is scalability also).

Later I use TensorFlow to calculate desired statistic (first multiplying matrices by themselves - then I have data only where `past` was true and later calculation of desired statistic (mean, count or whatever I want on rows of produced matrix). What is returned is vector of shape==parameters.shape.

**The second question - is there a better way to do that? By better of course I mean faster.**

EDIT
**Sample code**

````
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def multiply_time(param, time):
    if param.shape[0] == 1 or param.ndim == 1:
        _temp_param = np.ma.masked_equal(param * time, 0).data
    else:
        _temp_param = np.ma.masked_equal(np.sum(param, axis=1) * time, 0).data

    return_param = np.nanmean( np.where(_temp_param != 0, _temp_param, np.nan), axis=1)

    return return_param


horizon = np.timedelta64(10,'s')
increment = np.timedelta64(1,'s')

vector_len = 100
parameters = np.random.rand(vector_len)
# create time vector where distances between elements are not even
increment_vec = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(0,10,vector_len)*increment)
time = np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()) + increment_vec

past = (time < time[:, None]) & (time > (time - horizon )[:, None])
plt.imshow(past)
result = multiply_time(parameters, past)

import pandas as pd
pd_result = pd.DataFrame(parameters).rolling(10,1).mean()
plt.plot(time,result, c='r', label='desired')
plt.plot(time,parameters,c='g', label='original')
plt.plot(time,pd_result,c='b', label='pandas')
plt.legend()
plt.show()```


EDI2:

I guess we can close as answer with pandas rolling gives best results.
````

Comment: Does pandas's `rolling` function not do exactly this?  You can pass it a time horizon ("offset" in pandas lingo): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: is `horizon` a single number or is it the same shape as `time`? meaning is your horizon a constant value or variable per time? and what is the role of `parameters`?

Comment: Could you also please provide us with sample data and expected output to work with? I think you can do faster than above calculations.

Comment: @kevinsa5 - nope, rolling moves fixed window in terms of 'rows'. I want to shift by time. So rolling by 100 might roll by 3 minutes or 4,5 minutes. I want it to be fixed.

@Ehsan - yes, ```horizon``` is a scalar that could be described like ```horizon = np.timedelta64(15, 'm')```. The vector ```parameter``` is one that I want to calculate over (so for example calculate 15min mean of ```parameter``` for every point of it)

And yes, I'll provide an example tomorrow.

Comment: @Stefan please check the documentation of the "window" parameter of pandas's rolling.  Yes, it can move "by rows" like you describe, but you can also pass it an offset string like "15min" to roll across 15-minute windows, regardless of how many rows fall inside that horizon.  The docs: "If its an offset then this will be the time period of each window. Each window will be a variable sized based on the observations included in the time-period. This is only valid for datetimelike indexes."

Comment: @kevinsa5 you are right! that is bloody fast compared to my solution. Not sure why I didin't explore that option again (script is pretty old so might be that pandas was not supporting time input for rolling).
I also need to dig deeper into the calculation itself for own curiosity.